# Delete file when entity is deleted in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an entity `File()` that can be deleted. Linked to the entity, there is an actual file in `/upload` with the name `$file->getName()`. When the `File()` entity is deleted, what is the best way to remove the file as well? Should I do it in the Controller, or can I put a method to `File()` that is triggered when the entity is destroyed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to handle this case is using Doctrine lifecycle events (in your case, `preRemove` is a good choice).

You shouldn't handle it in your controller because your entity can be deleted any where (eg: in your service, cascade deletion...). Here is a list of [Doctrine Events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html) and Symfony documentation about [How to Work with Lifecycle Callbacks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html) or [How to Register Event Listeners and Subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) if you want to create your listener as a service with dependency injection.

Comment: Wouldn't be `postRemove` better if eg. deletion fails because of foreign key constraint?